# Почему API Яндекс геокодер иногда выдает, а иногда не выдает ответ, хотя количество символов в запросе одинаково?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Почему API Яндекс геокодер иногда выдает, а иногда не выдает ответ, хотя количество символов в параметре geocode одинаково и параметр bbox тоже одинаков?

Например:

1. на запрос
   "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81&format=json&results=15&apikey=<your_api_key>&rspn=1&bbox=38.7515,45.9959~49.0265,51.7342", где %D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81 = чиг, приходит пустой массив:
   "found": "0"
   }
   },
   "featureMember": [ ]
2. а на запрос
   "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81&format=json&results=15&apikey=<your_api_key>&rspn=1&bbox=38.7515,45.9959~49.0265,51.7342", где %D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81 = мос
   приходит не пустой массив со множеством значений

в bbox=38.7515,45.9959~49.0265,51.7342 точно попадает участок, где есть названия начинающиеся с "чиг". Допустим улица Чигиринская

Answer (score 1):

Если опираться на документацию, Геокодер только преобразовывает адрес в координаты и наоборот. Пытаясь искать в геокодере сочетания букв и неполные запросы вы ждёте от него то, что он делать не должен и не умеет.

Строки "чиг" и "мос" - не являются адресами. Сравнивая такие запросы со своей базой, геокодер может выдавать или не выдавать совершенно не связанные с вашей задачей результаты. И он не должен считать их начальными буквами адреса - это лишь ваше пожелание.

Все адреса в сервисе составлены согласно почтовому формату. И чем больше адрес похож на таковой в базе геокодера, тем более вероятным окажется его появление на первом месте ответа.

Под вашу задачу больше подходит метод [SuggestView](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/SuggestView.html) API Яндекс.Карт. А это пример его работы в их песочнице из документации:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/input_validation